# How to send a form automatically once a PHP variable isset?

Tags: php, forms

What's the best way to send this form automatically? I have a form above this that is used to set the `$amount` required in this one. As this form requires no user input (other than currently pressing submit) I'd like to send the form immediately after $amount isset so the user simply presses one button to set it and then is immediately redirected by this form.

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATED** (based on **sanki**'s answer)
I imagine this is *close to working* but I didn't give enough info in the first one.

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('#sub').click(function(){
 if( $("#amt").val() ) {
      $("#subbut").trigger("click");
 }
 });
</script>
</head>
```

Below is the form that sets `$price * 100 = $amount`

```
<form name="priceselect" id="priceselect" method="post">
  <select name="price" id="mySelect" onchange="document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML = this.value;">
    <option value="100">Option 1</option>
    <option value="120">Option 2</option>
    <option value="115">Option 3</option>
    <option value="135">Option 4</option>
    <option value="80" >Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <input value="Continue" type="Submit" id=sub />
</form>
```

The details for the form that wants submitting automatically are (added an echo to check $price is being POSTed):

```
<?php
$price = $_POST['price'];
if (isset($_POST['price'])) {
        echo "£";
        echo $price;
}

$merchantid = "XXXXXX";
$secret = "XXXXXX";

$timestamp = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

$orderid = $timestamp."-".mt_rand(1, 999);
$curr = "GBP";
$amount = $price * 100;

$tmp = "$timestamp.$merchantid.$orderid.$amount.$curr";
$md5hash = md5($tmp);
$tmp = "$md5hash.$secret";
$md5hash = md5($tmp);
?>
```

And then the form for automatic submission based on `$amount`/`$price` is:

```
<form id="globaliris" action="https://redirect.globaliris.com/epage.cgi" method="post" class="select">

<input type=hidden name="MERCHANT_ID" value="<?=$merchantid?>">
<input type=hidden name="ORDER_ID" value="<?=$orderid?>">
<input type=hidden name="CURRENCY" value="<?=$curr?>">
<input type=hidden name="AMOUNT" id="amt" value="<?=$amount?>">
<input type=hidden name="TIMESTAMP" value="<?=$timestamp?>">
<input type=hidden name="MD5HASH" value="<?=$md5hash?>">
<input type=hidden name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">
<br />
<br />
 <input style="visibility:hidden" value="Continue" id="subbut" type="Submit" />
</form>
```

(This is all on the same page )

Comment: Show what you have done for it .. ??

Comment: Submitting a form without actual user-submission sounds like a job for JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: At the moment I'd simply like to know the best way to go about it. I'm a noob and only really used PHP so far. From my reading cURL or AJAX may be the way to go, but I'm currently unsure.

Comment: @oGeez Thanks, do you think you could be more specific or link me to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added an ID in "AMOUNT" input type and ID="sub" to the first submit button.

```
<input value="Continue" type="Submit" id="sub" />


<input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" id="amt" value="<?=$amount?>">
```

Then try this jQuery Code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   if( $("#amt").val() > 0) {
     $("#subbut").trigger("click");
    }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: "so the user simply presses one button to set it", which button are you referencing here?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I've updated the post with more information. The button on the first form I hope to submit the second after it's refreshed

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! `(#amt)` seems to be throwing up a syntax error (sorry to keep coming back to you but I've never used jQuery)

Comment: Oh yes i missed double quotes around it. check the updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck. $price is echoing out fine after submitting the first form but the second one's still not submitting (I've edited the question again with your current answer)

Comment: well that's because after clicking the first submit button the page navigates to the action page. And thus it couldn't find the id "subbtn", where the click event must be triggered for the second form to be submitted.

Comment: Apologies, the first form comes back into the same page. the only code based on that form is `$price = $_POST['price'];` (all this code is on a single page, it obviously refreshes on submission from the first form)

Comment: If the page refreshes after first submit as you said try this code.
"    $(document).ready(function() {
 if( $("#amt").val() ) {
      $("#subbut").trigger("click");
 }
 });   "

Comment: THAT WORKS, I COULD KISS YOU. Although, the value of $amount is 0 by default, is there a way to change it so it doesn't redirect on 0 before it can be changed? (I'll obviously chose your answer once it's been updated, thanks again!)

Comment: I'm glad it worked, try the updated code. This will resolve the amount=0 issue.